# What are the chances of recovering the matrix for the given assumptions.

Tags: matrices, discrete-optimization

Let's assume I have a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$$  assume $x = a_1+b_1+c_1,y=a_2+b_2+c_3,z = a_3+b_3+c_3$, then I calculate the trace and determinant of the matrix.

Now given the values of $(x,y,z)$, trace, determinant, the range of $a_1....... c_3$ is between $0-7$ and are integers.

What are my chances or any other ways for me to get back to the original matrix?

Comment: I don't understand how a $3 \times 3$ matrix can equal a $3 \times 1$ one.

Comment: Consider it as a system of equations or I write a function on a matrix which gives me values $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: But they're still not equal.  They usually take the form $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, not $A = \mathbf{b}$.

Comment: You can write $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1\\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This might be the correct way to write.

Answer (score 0):

We have $5$ equations with $9$ unkowns, that is

- $a_1+b_1+c_1=x $
- $a_2+b_2+c_3=y $
- $a_3+b_3+c_3=z$
- $tr(A)=a_1+b_2+c_3=u$
- $\det(A)=v$

we could use the first $4$ linear equations as constraint and then search numerically for the solutions which satisfies the equation for the determinant for all the possible combination of the remaining $5$ free parameter, which means $8^5=2^{15}=32768$ trials.

Comment: @ user, So it is possible for me to write an algorithm or some code in any programming language that can search for these combinations is that correct?

Comment: Is there any other value of the matrix that I can store so I reduce the possible solutions?

Comment: Yes we can proceed numerically and find the solution(s).

Comment: I don’t understand the second question, sorry.

Comment: Can I calculate any other values from the matrix other than trace and determinant, so that number of possible solutions will be less than 32768

Comment: The sum of the columns also can help of course.